# What's the correct context for bpy.ops.mesh.rip_move()?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to write a script to rip and move the selected vertices of an object, but I keep getting an error that my context is incorrect. I'm writing this on Blender 3.3, but I suspect the context will be the same with newer version of Blender.

[image: Error message]

Here's my simplest test case that reproduces the error on the default cube scene. I've tried it both in Object mode and Edit mode. I have tried with `bpy.ops.mesh.rip()` instead of `rip_move()`, but still get the same error (and I need rip_move for my end project).

```
import bpy

# Find the default cube in the scene
my_obj = [obj for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects if obj.type == 'MESH'][0]
my_mesh = [m for m in bpy.data.meshes if m.name == my_obj.name][0]

rip_verts = [0, 1, 2] 

# Select the mesh
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = my_obj
bpy.data.objects[my_obj.name].select_set(True)

# Deselect the verts (all selected by default)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type='VERT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Select the verts. Counter-intuitively, you need to be in Object mode to select the verts
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
for index in rip_verts:
    my_mesh.vertices[index].select = True
    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') # I've tried this commented out, and still have issues

# Copy/pasted rip_move command from manually doing the operation.
bpy.ops.mesh.rip_move(MESH_OT_rip={"mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_fill":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0.696373, -0.770531, -0.101068), "orient_axis_ortho":'X', "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_elements":{'INCREMENT'}, "use_snap_project":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "use_snap_self":False, "use_snap_edit":False, "use_snap_nonedit":False, "use_snap_selectable":False, "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "view2d_edge_pan":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this simple example to work, but my full version of the code now works. I needed to add `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` as a parameter *and* call it from inside a class that extends `bpy.types.Operator`. Here's a rough approximation of what that looks like (not tested, just to give a rough idea).

````
class MyRipOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'my_tools.rip_mesh'
    bl_label = 'Rip it'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} # Enable undo

    def execute(self, context):
        # Select the verts you want to rip, just like the above example
        bpy.ops.mesh.rip_move('INVOKE_DEFAULT') # add whatever parameters you need after INVOKE_DEFAULT
        return {'FINISHED'}

```
````